# c++ queue mulithreading wait for jobs completed

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, jobs

Is there a c++ multithreading library in which there is a queue that can contain jobs that have to wait for other jobs to be completed. A threadpool is processing all jobs in the queue.

I want to write a multithreaded c++ program that produces and consumes jobs that are placed in a queue, only some of these jobs can only be processed when some other jobs already have been processed.

Similar like in qsub (grid queue manager), where you can put a job in a queue and that has to hold until other jobs have been finished.

Comment: How about `then` functionality?  Ie, each job in the thread pool provides `future` from the thread pool, and if you want to enqueue a new job when a particular job is finished you simply attach a `then` to said `future` that gets run (who cares where) when the `future` is ready?  It then enqueues the "dependent job" back into the threadpool.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? TBB, PPL, Boost Thread, std::packaged_task and std::future etc. etc.

Comment: @Yakk which (nonstandard?) implementation provides `then`?

Comment: My main programming language is Java, I am new to multithreading in c++ (I have some experience in Java). Frome sehe's post I gather that this kind of queue and multithreading is possible in C++. I'll search for a tutorial myself with the mentioned libraries. But any good links to a tutorial are much appreciated.

Comment: Submit the dependent jobs at the end of the jobs on which they depend?

Comment: @sehe None that I know of, it just isn't hard to write.  Create a task that waits on the future, and runs a functor when that future is done.  Doing it really cleanly and efficiently isn't easy, but writing `then` isn't hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found what I am looking for:

Task stealing like implemented in Intel Threading Building Block:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into what are called as Semaphores. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)

For instance you can write a semaphore using the  Boost Threading module. I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this talk by Herb Sutter. He gives an implementation for a C++11 style job.

[Herb Sutter - C++ Concurrency](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism)